# Change the color of the main title without redefining \maketitle

Tags: color, titles

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the main title of a document without redefining the `\maketitle`.  A Google search only yields how to systematically change the section titles that does not include the main title.

Comment: what is your document class?  what about `\title{\textcolor{blue}{The title}}`?

Comment: Yes that worked thank you.  I was thinking that there might be a `\titlecolor` definition or something.  I was overthinking it.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{\textcolor{blue}{The title}}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**Update** if `ams` class used

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{BLUE}{blue}
\title{\textcolor{blue}{The title}}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```